# PowerBI - How to show only 10 categories and wrap the rest on "Others"

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a customer service ticket list and need to build a report with it, one of the charts must be a "Qty per motive" and the problem is that I have too many motive to show on a chart, so I want to show let's say 10 of them and wrap the rest on a "Others" categories.
I've found some posts showing hot to do this with values like Sales, but I couldn't figure out how to make it work with a count on my data.

the structure of the data is like

ClientID | Ticket ID | Date | Motive | Description

In the posts that I've found the solution involves a SUM() and then sorting by the SUM() column, but I don't have a value column, I need to count per motive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to doing that.

1. **New group**
   use built-in PBI feature that you have to manually set up. Right-click on a column name in the *Fields* section and chose `New group`. A new window will pop up. There, you have to choose the categories you want to label as others. A new field (Column name (groups)) will appear in your table. This method requires you to decide arbitrarily which columns you want to be displayed.
2. **Create calculated table**
   You could create a brand new `Calculated table` in your model that is going to set new labels based on the total quantity. In that case, the labels will dynamically change rather than being static. If new motive comes to the model and its quantity will be in TOP N then it will be visible on the chart. This solution creates a separate table that you have to connect via relationship with your main table later.

Select `Calculated table` on the ribbon and then write DAX:

```
TopNCategories = 
VAR keepLabels = 3
VAR tbl = 
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        VALUES( 'Product'[Brand] ),
        "@TotalSales", CALCULATE( [Sales Amount] )
    )
VAR addRank =
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        tbl,
        "@Rank", 
            RANKX(
                tbl,
                [@TotalSales],
                ,
                DESC
            )
    )
VAR result =
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        addRank,
        "BrandKey", 'Product'[Brand],
        "NewLabel", IF( [@Rank] <= keepLabels, 'Product'[Brand], "Others" )
    )
RETURN
    result
```

3. **Calculated column**
   If you don't want to create another instance in your model, you can use the above logic to create a set of `Calculated column` in your main table instead. Depends on your model size and cardinality, this solution may have an impact on the performance of the whole report.